# После оформления заказа корзина в битрикс очищается, но CSaleBasket::GetList продолжает возвращать элементы заказа

Tags: битрикс, корзина

Корзина работает как компонент bitrix:sale.basket.basket, и после оформления заказа она показывает, что пуста, но при этом, когда пытаюсь получить корзину через `CSaleBasket::GetList(array(),array("FUSER_ID" => CSaleBasket::GetBasketUserID()),false,false,array());` мне возвращается список товаров, которые я когда-либо заказывал. Заказ оформляется не стандартным компонентом, а с помощью API. Код, который за это отвечает:

````
                $order->setBasket($basket);
        
                $basketSum = $order->getPrice();
        
                $propertyCollection = $order->getPropertyCollection();
                $propertyCodeToId = array();

                foreach($propertyCollection as $propertyValue){
                    $propertyCodeToId[$propertyValue->getField('CODE')] = $propertyValue->getField('ORDER_PROPS_ID');
                }

                $propertyValue=$propertyCollection->getItemByOrderPropertyId($propertyCodeToId['FIO']);
                $propertyValue->setValue($fio);

                $propertyValue=$propertyCollection->getItemByOrderPropertyId($propertyCodeToId['PHONE']);
                $propertyValue->setValue($phone);

                $propertyValue=$propertyCollection->getItemByOrderPropertyId($propertyCodeToId['EMAIL']);
                $propertyValue->setValue($email);
                
        
                $order->doFinalAction(true);
                $result = $order->save();```
````

Comment: Корзина при оформлении заказа получается так: ```$basket = \Bitrix\Sale\Basket::loadItemsForFUser(\Bitrix\Sale\Fuser::getId(), $siteId)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CSaleBasket::GetList(
    array(),
    array(
        "FUSER_ID" => CSaleBasket::GetBasketUserID(),
        "ORDER_ID" => "NULL"
    ),
    false,
    false,
    array()
);
```